# how to create alert confirm box in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, alert

i want to show a dialog box before deleting a files, how i can do it with vue?

here what i try

my button to delete a file

```
<a href="javascript:;" v-on:click="DeleteUser(artist.id, index)" onClick="return confirm('are you sure?');">Delete</a>
```

and here my delete method

```
DeleteUser(id, index) {
                axios.delete('/api/artist/'+id)
                .then(resp => {
                    this.artists.data.splice(index, 1);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            },
```

the dialog is showing but whatever i choose it keep delete the file.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="javascript:;" v-on:click="DeleteUser(artist.id, index)">Delete</a>

DeleteUser(id, index) {

   if(confirm("Do you really want to delete?")){

                axios.delete('/api/artist/'+id)
                .then(resp => {
                    this.artists.data.splice(index, 1);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
   }
},
```

Comment: if you are using `{{$t('some_label')}}` for translations, you can access t inside the functions like this : `if (confirm(this.$t('delete_entry'))) {`

Answer (score 13):

Simply use `if(confirm('are you sure?'))` inside `DeleteUser`.

```
DeleteUser(id, index) {
    if(confirm('are you sure?'))
        axios.delete('/api/artist/'+id)
          .then(resp => {
          this.artists.data.splice(index, 1);
        })
          .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
},
```

and remove the `onClick`

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/ho86n3mu/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can install an alert library (Simple Alert) from [here](https://vuejsexamples.com/simple-alert-for-vue-js/) for more beautiful view

And then, you can use options to show alert box with question or anything else. This library has a few option. You can see them if you check above link.

```
this.$confirm("Are you sure ?", "Class is deleting...", "question").then(()=>{

           axios.delete("/classes/" + studentClass.id).then(response =>{
                this.$alert(response.data.message, 'Succes', 'success');
           }).catch(error => {
               this.$alert(error.response.data.message, 'Hata', 'error');
           });

       });
```

Description of alert box with parameters :

**`this.$confirm('Message is here', "Title is here", "type is here like success, question, warning");`**

Answer (score -1):

For the case of using the Quasar Framework, you can use this plugin. I use globally !

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    confirm() {
      this.$q.dialog({
        title: 'Confirm',
        message: 'Would you like to turn on the wifi?',
        cancel: true,
        persistent: true
      }).onOk(() => {
        // console.log('>>>> OK')
      }).onOk(() => {
        // console.log('>>>> second OK catcher')
      }).onCancel(() => {
        // console.log('>>>> Cancel')
      }).onDismiss(() => {
        // console.log('I am triggered on both OK and Cancel')
      })
    }


  }
}
```

```html
<q-btn label="Prompt" color="primary" @click="prompt" />
```

[Quasar Dialog](https://v1.quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/dialog)

Comment: Why pull a whole library for a small confirm dialog?