# Form submission before route leave in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am new to VueJs and I'm stuck in a problem. I am creating a form and want to show a alert dialog with message "you might lose the data, please save the data before you leave." and when i click on yes it should submit the form and change the the route.

I know that we can do this with `beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next)` but how do i submit the form before route leave on clicking yes in alert box?

[image]
in above image my route is `/create` when

```
handleArticleSubmit() {
    // Collect form data
    let formData = new FormData();

    // Start Button Loading
    this.isSubmittingArticle = true;
    axios
      .post("/articles", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        // Stop button loading
        this.isSubmittingArticle = false;
        // Show alert message
        this.snackbar = {
          isVisible: true,
          color: "success",
          text: "Article submited successfully"
        };

      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Stop button loading
        this.isSubmittingArticle = false;
        // Show alert
          // Show alert message
          this.snackbar = {
            isVisible: true,
            color: "error",
            text: error
          };
        }
      });
  }
},
```

above mentioned code saves the article i want to change the route if form submits with all validation validation (like blank, number etc.) if not then should not change the route.
thanks
right now i am using this code to change route:

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
  const answer = window.confirm(
    "you might lose the data, please save the data before you leave."
  );
  if (answer) {
    this.handleArticleSaveDraft();
    next();
  } else {
    next(false);
}
```

thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54156534

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-dialog

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for reply but i want to use both mentioned things in beforeRouteLeave()

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: @Dhruvil Dave  See the updated comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edited comment

You need to take care of these:

1. **Promisify** the handleArticleSubmit method
2. Make *beforeRouteLeave* **asynchronous**
3. Use **try**/**cache** to check the promise, so if it is rejected (form has an error) page does not change, you can also log the error if you want.

**See how it is implemented below:**

---

```
methods: {
    handleArticleSubmit() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {   // 1. Promisify the method                  
            let formData = new FormData() 
            this.isSubmittingArticle = true 
            axios
            .post("/articles", formData, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                }
            })
            .then(res => {        
                this.isSubmittingArticle = false         
                this.snackbar = { 
                    isVisible: true,
                    color: "success",
                    text: "Article submited successfully"
                }
                resolve() // Resolve the promise (all is good)
            })
            .catch(error => {        
                this.isSubmittingArticle = false         
                this.snackbar = { // Show alert message
                    isVisible: true,
                    color: "error",
                    text: error
                }   
                reject(error) // Reject it when error happens
            })
        })
    }
},
async beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) { // 2. Make this async
    let answer = window.confirm("you might lose the data, please save the data before you leave.")
    if (answer) {
        // 3. Try/catch to confirm the resolve
        try{ 
            await this.handleArticleSubmit() 
            // Resolved
            next() 
        } catch (err) { // Rejected
            next(false)
            log(err)
        }                
    } else {
        next(false)
    }
}
```

---

### Old comment

This is specifically mentioned in the [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) as Leave Guard, in Vue Router documentation.

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  const answer = window.confirm('you might lose the data, please save the data before you leave.')
  if (answer) {
    this.submit() // Submit your form here however you want
    next()
  } else {
    next(false)
  }
}
```

Or if you have a custom modal system, make it asynchronous, and make sure your modal is returning a promise:

```
async beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  const answer = await this.openModal()
  if (answer) {
    this.submit() // Submit your form here however you want
    next()
  } else {
    next(false)
  }
}
```